# Was Switzerland really impossible to invade during WW2?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, war, warfare, switzerland

My question is not about an alternative scenario, nor about the reasons that caused Switzerland to not get invaded (as could be seen here: *[Why was Switzerland not attacked during the two World Wars?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/8704/why-was-switzerland-not-attacked-during-the-two-world-wars)*). I am asking about if the Swiss military of WW2 is clearly overrated.

Many people claim that the country was (and still is) impossible to invade due to the mountains and the guns owned by Swiss citizens. But there are many examples of similar situations that happened in history, as exposed in the question below, that show very clearly that those reasons are not sufficient to exclude an invasion and occupation.

---

- Often, people make the claim that, given the mountainous terrain of Switzerland, an invasion would have been close to impossible. However, the Germans successfully invaded Norway, Yugoslavia, and Greece, all of which also have mountainous terrain, **and they did that in a matter of days/ weeks**. Also, Switzerland is much closer to Germany than Greece and Norway, so bringing new troops and supply would have been quicker and easier.
- For the same reason, it is generally said that in case of invasion, the Swiss army, under the command of general Henri Guisan, would have retreated into the mountain strongholds, leaving much of the population and economical/ industrial centers to the invader. This is the so called "National Redoubt" strategy. However, why would the German and Italian armies need to attack those strongholds in the mountains? Why could they not simply occupy the Swiss plateau, then wait and let the Swiss soldiers starve to death in their mountain fortresses? Feeding 800,000+ soldiers in the Alps for months if not years isn't realistic. Plus, their ammunition stocks would be limited, while the Axis could bring as much supplies as they want to.
- Then, there is the argument that, given the vast majority of Swiss men who own guns at home, even in case of German victory, there would be guerrilla warfare. However, if I am correct, the German army knew quite well how to deal efficiently with rebels in its occupied territories. They could simply retaliate on the village or region, thus causing the rebels to think twice before deciding to do something. And anyway, wouldn't this guerrilla warfare calm down after a few years, when people become accustomed to German and Italian rules?
- In case of invasion, the Axis would benefit from the surprise effect, given that they would be the one attacking:

  1. First, that means that at least the border cities of Geneva and Basel would have fallen quickly.
  2. Then, that also means that the Swiss army would not be able to destroy all the roads, railways and other means of communications before retreating from regions close to the borders. Thus, the German army would potentially advance relatively quickly in the first few hours.
  3. That also means that parachutists could be dropped behind Swiss lines to secure important positions. Like strategic areas in the Jura mountains to prevent the Swiss from using them as a defensive line. Given the close proximity to the border with occupied France, wouldn't the German army then be able to quickly secure the Jura Mountains, thus having free room for an invasion of the plateau?
  4. Fourth, and most importantly, the Blitzkrieg tactic could still be used in the plateau. That means that, especially in the first hours of the invasion, the German Luftwaffe could simply bomb each and every Swiss military position on the Plateau, which would then allow for its conquest. And then, as said, one could just wait for the Swiss army to starve in their mountains and finally surrender (or die).
- As pointed out by User @Mastrem and after doing some research, another very important argument that I was completely unaware of is that the German Secret Service, led by Admiral Wilhelm Canaris, knew A LOT about the Swiss military defence system. In fact, most of the Swiss defence system, including the "Réduit national (National Redoubt)" was thoroughly infiltrated by German spies, even before the beginning of the war. More can be read here for example: https://www.swissinfo.ch/blueprint/servlet/eng/war-time-german-secret-service-spied-chinks-in-swiss-armour/1474146

There are probably more reasons, but those are the main ones that I found. Was Switzerland much easier to conquer than imagined?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97621/discussion-on-question-by-ryukyu-was-switzerland-really-impossible-to-invade-dur).

Comment: I don't have a good source for this right now, but I think I read somewhere that Admiral Canaris, head of the Abwehr, and General Walter Schellenberg exaggerated the Swiss defense capabilities in order to prevent operation Tannenbaum.

Comment: Not so much "impossible" as "they made it not worth it". I cover this in [my answer to How was Switzerland able to stay neutral during WWI and WWII?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/34367/how-was-switzerland-able-to-stay-neutral-during-wwi-and-wwii). "*By not being a threat, and having no strategic benefit to either side worth fighting a professional army on excellent defensive terrain.*"

Comment: While we have mountains in Norway, it is not as they provide natural protection from invasions. Most of our larger cities lie on the coast and several of them were taken in 1940 by dropping paratroops on nearby airports, flying larger forces in once the airports were more or less secure and mooring ships with the rest of the invasion force somewhere near the cities.

Comment: @Ryukyu: Those hilly areas are also not all that easy to invade with a mechanized army.  If you hike or bike along the Jura border with France, you can (or could as of the mid-2000s) see that little roads & tracks still have anti-tank barriers in place.

Comment: " while the Axis could bring as much supplies as they want to." - in theory. In practice, the Axis was short on a lot of stuff, most notably oil. Their Blitzkrieg strategy was a do-or-die one: their capacity to fight wars of attrition was limited.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but there is an interesting video on YouTube 'America's War with Switzerland' by Mark Felton Productions, about the many accidental violations of Swiss air space in World War II by American planes, including bombing a Swiss town mistaken for one in Germany, and the response from the Swiss airforce. There were several aerial combats and a number of American planes shot down by the Swiss and their crews interned until the end of the war.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Ok, since I think I finally got your *real* question (as I see it):

> I'm simply asking if the defense of Switzerland during WW2 was overrated. **Many people claim that the country was impossible to occupy**, I just want to know if this is not clearly exaggerated.

The emphasis is what **I** interpret as your "real" question (since there is a lot of confusion here) and will answer it.

First of all, you probably have the wrong impression (partly).
Switzerland never tried and was never seen as impossible to invade, even their well-planned defense wasn't impenetrable, and everyone knew that.

The *only* point was to make a possible invasion (*and occupation*) so costly that it would never be worth it.

You got it right that the invasion would be over very quick, *however*, you go wrong with this one:

> Feeding 800 000+ soldiers in the Alps for months if not years isn't realistic.

Because they were well prepared to hold out in their bunkers (and go raiding from there) for an extended amount of time.

And then we come to your "real" question (IMHO), which is not the *invasion*, but the *occupation*.

And that is where another of your questions comes in:

> why would the German and Italian armies need to attack those strongholds in the mountains?

Because the Swiss planned to constantly attack out from these forts, waging a heavy and costly guerilla warfare from against the occupying troops.

This means Germany would have had two options:
A) attack the forts, which would be time, supply and manpower-costly to no end.
B) endure the terrorism

And B) would be costly. The French resistance could be dealt with (somewhat) because they were few, mostly untrained civilians with (mostly) scavenged equipment. And they did their part, too. Now imagine that, but with 80k well trained, drilled, coordinated and fully equipped soldiers.
Yeah, Germany would have pretty much a third front right in their backyard for years, which would have been unacceptable.

**TLDR:**
Switzerland would have been hard (but possible) to invade, but almost impossible to occupy.

Comment: Probably, but I doubt you'd get that much more info, because the information on the topic just isn't there and the main point all depends on the hypothetical retreated swiss army actually terrorizing to the last man, which is debateable

Comment: @Ryukyu the greek were well prepared for fighting the invasion, but had no real plans for handling the occupation. 
That's the difference , the Swiss were fully prepared to give up  most of the land (but none of the army)

Comment: This is not true though.  Switzerland did not have "80,000 well trained and fully equipped soldiers".  They had civilians with light rifles.  They had virtually no heavy weaponry, machine guns, artillery, and certainly no air support or anti-aircraft capabilities.  The fact that Swiss civilians were equipped with rifles and did target practise does ***NOT*** make them soldiers.  At least the French resistance had some veterans from WWI; the Swiss did not even have civilians who'd seen battle.

Comment: @Graham The National Redoubt was full of artillery, flak cannons, and machine guns. The Swiss Air Force had over 100 bf109s and a similar number of other planes by the end of 1940.

Comment: @Graham no they were not simple  civilians, but trained servicemen, after the initial training, had to serve **yearly** between three to four weeks as refresher courses. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscription_in_Switzerland

Comment: @Hobbamok, some information is certainly there: Germany did detailed planning on what it would take to invade Switzerland as "Operation Tannenbaum".

Comment: It is may worth adding that the Mountains of Switzerland basically cut Italy and Germany in two. So moving good from Italy to Germany and vice versa would have been heavily reduced.

Comment: @Graham, they were, as basically _any_ armies back in that time, a militia and not a "professional" army as e.g. Germany, US etc today. So they were a full army. With all the equipment, no difference to any other army back then.

Comment: I get the feeling that "already" in the second-to-last paragraph doesn't really say what you want to say.  Maybe "as well" would be better, or  just "too".

Comment: @Hobbamok Do you have any sources regarding housing/feeding/supplying 800k soldiers (and presumably the necessary civilians) for months? No matter how well prepared they were, that sounds unlikely. You also went with 80k soldiers further down in your answer, which sounds much more reasonable to me.

Comment: @Leherenn 80k was pulled out of thin air and the numbers in general are irrelevant. THe 800k was a quote from their question, I omitted/forgot to add that obviously not all of them would go and hide out. Some might also merge into the civilian population and stay ready from there.

Answer (score 53):

No country is impossible to invade.  Andorra could invade the USA.

The question you should have asked was "Was Switzerland Impossible to Conquer during World War II?".

The answer is no country is impossible to conquer.  But there is great variation in the probability that a specific country will actually conquer another specific country if it tries to do so during a specific moment in time.

So the question you really should have asked was "How Hard Would it Have Been for the Axis to Invade and conquer Switzerland During World War II?"

A big part of Switzerland is highly mountainous.  The Swiss army trained a lot of conscripts who went into the reserves after serving a short time and could be activated to serve in war.  The Swisss government established various fortifications in the mountainous regions to hold out against hypothetical invaders.

Switzerland would have been harder to conquer per unit of territory or per unit of poplulation than many other European countries were.  Starting an unnecessary war with Switzerland while World War Two was being fought would have been foolish.

Hitler is criticized for starting wars with the USSR and the USA while the war with Britain was ongoing, but Hitler wasn't totally reckless.  He felt that the USSR would probably attack Germany in the future and thought he needed to attack the USSR first before they were ready, and he considered the USA to be already actively supporting Germany's enemies.

Switzerland wasn't threatening to attack Germany and it was surrounded by Axis powers so it couldn't export anything to help the Allies against the will of the Axis, and the Swiss government usually tried to be as neutral as possible, and to seem to other states to be neutral.

So basically even Hitler could see no reason to invade Switzerland during World War TWo when it would have a diversion of military resources from fighting more powerful and immediately threatening enemies.

Even though the Axis countries invaded a lot of countries during World War II, there were a number of other countries they didn't invade.  Obviously the Axis leaders didn't consider the desirability of invading those countries worth the trouble at the moment.

Considering that the Axis invaded the mighty USSR and declared war on the mighty USA, I expect that if the Axis won World War II, had millions of soldiers available, and was sufficiently motivated to invade Switzerland, they would have invaded and conquered Switzerland despite the problems and difficulties.

Comment: Finally the makings of a good answer. Volumes 2 and 3 of Jack Gill's ***Thunder on the Danube 1809*** goes into great detail on the difficulties that the Bavarians and French had in suppressing Tyrolean guerrillas and partisans through the spring and summer of 1809, even in the absence of any regular Austrian forces. The German General Staff would have been well aware of this campaign.

Comment: Well, we'd better git them suckers before they git us! Stands to reason.

Comment: Switzerland is small and landlocked.  It is hard to imagine it holding out against a large industrial military state that surrounded it on all sides if that state thought it was worth the cost.  But note that "conquer" and "suppress all guerrillas" aren't the same thing.

Comment: Note also that while private gun ownership was banned in Nazi Germany - even today it remains at an estimated 28%.

Comment: Good answer, but I think you need to expand it. Outside comic books (and movies derived from them) no one goes conquering just for fun.The question is always "Is the effort to conquer X worth the benefits?" How much would Nazi Germany lose if Switzerland was an unconquered enclave? It would have been a client state no matter what. (And sometimes client states are the most efficient way to run an empire.

Comment: Did you deliberately choose Andorra as a country whose military budget wouldn't stretch to a single one-way air fare to the US?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: I suspect the mention of Andorra is inspired by ***The Grand Duchy of Fenwick*** from *The Mouse that Roared*.

Comment: @Ryukyu, you don't need to delete the question and re-ask it, but you can edit both the question title and body. It is customary to hold back with that if there are already a lot of good answers, or if it would make the top (especially an accepted) answer take on a very different meaning; but if there is no confusion of any kind, feel free!

Comment: This answer seems to address a different and much broader question (is it possible for any country to be "impossible" to invade) but doesn't really have much content that is specifically relevant to Switzerland.

Answer (score 26):

What factors were Hitler's / Germany's motivations for WW2? Revanchism, stealing raw materials, and racial hatreds.

The Swiss are largely German-speaking / Germanic, so there's no "racial superiority" factor to promote invasion and de facto depopulation/extermination and colonization.

They don't have a excessive amount of arable land for "true German" settlers.

Given their neutrality, they were no threat to Germany, and were probably convenient as a neutral middleman.

They weren't an easy target (either culturally or geographically) like Denmark or the Low Countries.

An invasion would have been fiercely opposed, and a distraction from Barbarossa.

Comment: @ryukyu as far as I remember, the Swiss army assumed they would lose the lowlands, but retain the highlands. After that: wait and see how things envolved. They did not believe they wwould protect everyting, nor loose everything.

Comment: `The Swiss are largely German-speaking / Germanic, so there's no "racial superiority" factor to promote invasion and de facto depopulation/extermination and colonization.` The same could be said of Austria and Luxemburg and The Netherlands, Flanders, Denmark, Norway... yet all of those germanic lands were invaded by Germans at some point.

Comment: @Bregalad - Isn't that what the next 4 paragraphs address?

Comment: @Bregalad Switzerland has a long and successful history of not being part of any of the relevant empires. There was no easy ideological justification for annexing Switzerland. Also, the Swiss territory is inconveniently mountainous and thus had no strategic relevance for invading France, different to the Low Countries. Norway was vulnerable to Allied invasions, which would have denied critical resources to Nazi Germany. As for Denmark, it would have been disadvantageous  to *not* occupy it since it was both the gate to Scandinavia and into the Baltic sea.

Comment: Compared to that, Austria's separate existence was seen as an unfortunate consequence of WW I. The treaties of Versailles and Saint-Germain forbade Austria from joining Germany. Austria could not hold on to the language islands South Tyrol, Lower Styria and the so-called Sudetenland, and struggled economically, at least in its early years. Most Austrians saw no point in remaining separate after the sundering of the Habsburg empire. After all, its power was the reason Austria did not join the German Empire in 1871. Ironically, opinions later changed after the Nazis gained power in Germany.

Comment: I suspect this may be more important that many answers are considering. There is a political aspect to this. Even in an authoritarian dictatorship you need a _casus belli_ if you expect the people and your rank-and-file military to support an invasion and to lessen the chances of upsetting the rest of the world.

Comment: Geographically is understandable, but what do you mean by a culturally easy target?

Comment: @MauganRa By that logic, Switzerland's separate existance could be seen as "an unfortunate consequence of the 30-years wars". However I agree there's a difference and I see your point.

Comment: @Peter, I think I was vaguely thinking of their fierce commitment to independence and neutrality and their social norm of everyone having a rifle in their house and being callable-up to reserve units. This isn't to say that thousands of Dutch wouldn't have, and didn't, give their lives to defend their country, so yep, I think my point there about culture is kind of evaporating away a bit.

Comment: @MauganRa Prussia didn't want Austria as a member of the German Confederacy ! Unwanted competition due to the fact that Prussia and Austria before 1866 were the dominant forces in the Confederacy. We can't longterm neither have two emperors in the same constellation.

Answer (score 24):

The Germans were certain they could. For instance, their 1940 plans for [Operation Tannenbaum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Tannenbaum) estimated that a force of 300,000 to 500,000 men would have been sufficient.

Swiss military leadership also thought that an invasion would have been successful: Their revised military plan for the event of an invasion, the [Réduit national](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Redoubt_(Switzerland)#Guisan_plan), called for a delaying action at the border to allow the majority of the army to withdraw into mountain fortresses, effectively ceding control of all major population and industrial centers to the enemy.

In summary, neither side doubted that a German invasion would be successful if a sufficient proportion of Germany's military might were allocated to that task. It's just that Hitler had different priorities at the time. In Hitler's own words:

> Die Schweiz, das kleine Stachelschwein, nehmen wir im Rückzug ein

In English:

> Switzerland, the small porcupine, we'll conquer on the way back.

(Granted, the quote is from an earlier time in the war, but it is such an apt summary of Germany's leadership's dismissive attitude towards the Swiss military, that I thought it relevant anyway)

Answer (score 11):

There were many practical reasons why Switzerland was not occupied

- of which **none** of the first answer of @AmorphouBob apply

Some of these reasons are:

- militarily Switzerland was considered a 'thorny' problem,  as expressed in the question and the [Swiss strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Guisan#General)
- there was no **strategic advantage** (Switzerland was surrounded by the Axis powers)
- an economic **disadvantage** as a source of foreign currency and products
- <s>an **disadvantage** of the loss of information from Allied areas (weekly air fights from Britain, with newspapers etc.)</s> (source not yet found)

Further details about [Switzerland in World War II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switzerland_during_the_World_Wars#World_War_II), dealing with the first 3 points in more detail.

---

Please forget everything you learned about Germany during WW2 from TV series like [Hogan's Heroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hogan%27s_Heroes), where the people are portrayed as bumbling idiots.

They were everything but.

They knew exactly what they were doing and almost succeeded

- taking over a greater part of Europe
- mass murder of millions of deemed 'undesirables'
- destruction of whole countries
- corruption of generations of people
- and a list that is almost endless

There is no need, at every opportunity, for others to **invent**, at every opportunity available, something new based on that persons imagination and (it would seem) **their** need to add, over 70 years after the horror ended, a new scene to a Hollywood film or television series.

- the verified, factual facts are more than sufficient to portrait what horrors humans are capable of

---

## Answer:

Switzerland was not occupied because it was not in the interest of Germany to do so, during that period of time, for the above given reasons.

Comment: @ryukyu as  answered as comment in the other answer: they, internaly, did not think themselves as 'invincible', but had a pragmatic accessment of what could be achived. Loss of lowlands, retainment of heighlands. German assessments were taking the highlads would be difficult and costly. Unrestricted Transit to Italy would be the only the only positive aspect of an occupation. Without the highlands that would not be possible. Final judgment: leave things as they are. In the end  the Swiss statagie worked.

Comment: The best answer so far - but recall that mountains are very poor tank country, and the lesson of the Tyrolean rebellion against the Bavarians in 1809 is that suppressing rebels in the Alps is a long and difficult process.

Comment: @ryukyu I have added a source from where I read about the Swiss strategy

Comment: Too little actual useful answer (even the listed reasons are dubious - foreign currency wasn't a problem in any other country they occupied, and what does British newspapers to do with it?), and most of the answer is just off-topic rambling.

Comment: I think your assessment of nazi germany in the war is also somewhat overblown. They weren't bumbling idiots, but they also weren't genius ubermensch. An insane and unsustainable ideology drove all decision making, which was the essence of their downfall. The truth is that they were just mostly just regular people with some strokes of brilliance and some total blunders, and that's what's really terrifying

Comment: @llama Everything you meantioned has nothing to do with the question.  CH had a strategy that worked for them. Germany's analysis of of that strategy led them to their conclusion, which also worked for them. End of answer to question. Other answers, however, contained elements that had nothing to do with the question and thus does help in understanding how both reacted. This is  what I object to, thus the extra statements. These unnecessary elements is what is overblown (and not only for this question , but also in others).

Comment: Unless you're fighting in the jungle, those at an **economic disadvantage** WILL LOSE.

Comment: @Mazura be it as in may,  Switzerland's strategy worked. WW1 and WW2 avoided occupation ; 1930s avoided Italian irredentism. That a 3:0 success, as aposed to Belgien 0:2 and Netherlands 0:1. What more do you want?

Comment: correction: Netherlands 1:1

Comment: "Switzerland was able to remain independent through a combination of military deterrence, economic concessions to Germany and good fortune as larger events during the war delayed an invasion." - *'economic concessions'*, that's what I want a cite for, and (if you've been reading the [comment thread on Russell's answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/54231/8156), why I want it tied into "some higher-ranking officers within the Swiss Army had pro-Nazi sympathies"

Comment: @Mazura you should concentrate more on what people due to survive after getting cought up in a conflict that was **not** of there making.

Answer (score 6):

This is an hypothetical question. I'll try to answer based only on the military concept.

You have already answered your own question, in part 4. You don't need to conquer the whole country; only the main cities and the fields are desirable. Forget about the mountains; you don't need them. Once in a while they'll have to attack some places to prevent guerrilla activities, but no more than that.

That is what happened in Yugoslavia and in the early stages of the invasion of Russia. The attack was so fast that the country did not have time to defend, so some people with military preparation defended themselves as guerrillas. Woods, swamps, deserts, jungles, and mountains were not occupied, so guerrillas went there.

Remember that from military point of view, you only need to destroy the enemy capability to resist and fulfill your political objectives. You don't need to occupy the whole territory; there is no need for that.

Think of the war in North Africa. The war only happened near the coast and in some oasis, not in the whole Sahara, and there isn't any need to fight there.

Think in the war in the Pacific. Several islands where ignored, while only the important ones were invaded.

Finally, think in the territories occupied by Germany and Japan at the end of the war. The allies did not need to occupy them before the end of the war. They only arrived there after winning the war.

Comment: @Ryukyu Indeed, you are right. I mean is "hypothetical" under the rules of this site. Because it did not happened, formally this is not part of history. But the question is valid anyway.

Comment: This is a terrible answer - every factual claim it makes is incorrect. Tito's partisans effectively ousted the German army from Yugoslavia before the Soviets arrived. Civilian guns were banned in the Soviet Union, so no partisan activity was possible until those were supplied. The Gazala line in May 1942 stretched nearly 80 miles into the Sahara, and Rommel won by extending his forces further into the desert than Wavell, isolating and cutting British supply. If the Japanese had maintained a functional navy instead of losing at Midway, MacArthur's island hopping would have been much harder.

Comment: I can't parse the final paragraph.  At the end of the war, Germany and Japan surrendered and no longer occupied any territories.

Comment: @Ryukyu what you could edit to make it more clear was: What do YOU see as "successfully invaded" ? Because the World isnt a strategy Game where you win as soon as the capital is taken.
Especially Switzerland was 100% prepared (and planned) to loose its cities and wage a guerilla war from the Alpine bunkers. 
Aka. on paper they would've been "captured" while in fact they would never really loose until the Germans retreated due to the costs

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Partisan activity in Soviet Union started because people had to take refugee from mass assasinations performed by Germany. 80 miles in a desert of 1000 miles is nothing. While the comment about japanese navy is correct. But the point in the answer is different, is about the need of occupy the whole territory, instead of just defeat the enemy's army or occupy the useful territory. Any of those alternatives are valid.

Comment: @gerrit The point is that Germany and Japan surrender while still having territory under their control. Germany had part of Czechia, Latvia and Neederlands, and the whole Denmark and Norway. While Japan had control over some territories in China, Indonesia, Vietnam and Thailand.

Comment: @Ryukyu This is an X-Y situation.  You're asking if Switzerland's military was so strong that it _could not_ be invaded.  But that isn't the right question.  As several people have answered, they knew they _could_ be successfully invaded, but that didn't matter, so long as it was clear to the German planners that the cost of such an invasion would outweigh its benefits.  Left neutral, Switzerland was not a threat to the Axis.  The resources that would have been tied down occupying it were thought better used elsewhere.  The defenses were good enough to make it not _worth_ invading.

Answer (score 5):

**Shields up!!!**

It was advantageous for the Germans not to conquer Switzerland, and this would be a major factor in deciding the merit of doing so. A few only examples:

Switzerland provided the Nazis access to bank accounts and "safe" deposits of Jews and others. Exactly how these were divied up is unknown to me, but one can safely assume that the Nazis did not get 100% of the take. Without Swiss cooperation you would be far more liable to get a situation such as with the French art treasures which were very largely spirited away by the French (with assistance by the German assigned to "protect them for the Germans).

The Swiss were the international 'good-guys' [tm]  who controlled the distribution of Red Cross parcels. They colluded with the Japanese to divert a substantial proportion of the funds intended for Red Cross Food Parcels intended for Allied prisoners of War in Japanese hands, and divided the spoils between them. While that is Japan and not Germany, I'd be surprised if the idea came to them that late in the piece.

I believe these answers are based on factual accounts of Swiss actions.
By all means disabuse me of this impression if appropriate.

---

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97752/discussion-on-answer-by-russell-mcmahon-was-switzerland-really-impossible-to-inv).

Answer (score 3):

#### Impossibility of an invasion

My answer is based on wikipedia article [Operation Tannenbaum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Tannenbaum), which is about German plans for war against Switzerland during WW2:

> Germany started planning the invasion of Switzerland on 25 June 1940, the day that France surrendered. At this point, the German army in France consisted of three groups with **two million soldiers in 102 divisions**.
>
> [..]
>
> The German plan continued to undergo revision until October, when the 12th Army submitted its fourth draft, now called Operation Tannenbaum. The original plan had called for 21 German divisions, but that figure was downsized to 11 by the OKH. Halder himself had studied the border areas, and concluded that the "Jura frontier offers no favorable base for an attack. Switzerland rises, in successive waves of forest-covered terrain across the axis of an attack. The crossing points on the river Doubs and the border are few; the Swiss frontier position is strong." He decided on an infantry feint in the Jura in order to draw out the Swiss Army and then cut it off in the rear, as had been done in France. With the **11 German divisions and roughly 15 more Italian divisions** prepared to enter from the south, the Axis plans were to invade Switzerland with somewhere **between 300,000 and 500,000 men**.

This means that Germany considered a force of 11 of its own and 15 Italian divisions enough to invade and conquer Switzerland. This number represents only a small part of its forces at the time. There is no doubt that an invasion would have been possible and ultimately succeeded.

If Germany didn't invade Switzerland, it wasn't because of an unsurmountable Swiss military strength but because of a cost-benefit analysis.

#### Costs and benefits of an invasion

In the case of an invasion the lowlands in northern Switzerland would have been taken quickly. However, the bulk of the Swiss forces would have continued to resist for months in the mountains (National Reduit) and even after defeating all regular forces guerilla attacks would have continued. The war-torn (and at that time much poorer) country wouldn't have provided many resources but instead required a substantial and permanent military presence. Furthermore, a long-lasting and bloody war against Switzerland - and in particular its German(-speaking) population - would have been highly unpopular in Germany and among the soldiers as there were no historical grievances to exploit.

On the other hand, Germany could benefit in some ways from a neutral, pliable Switzerland. The Swiss industry was heavily reliant on Germany for coal (Germany provided 41 per cent of Swiss energy needs according to [Was Switzerland neutral or a Nazi ally in World War Two?](http://www.historyisnowmagazine.com/blog/2016/2/14/was-switzerland-neutral-or-a-nazi-ally-in-world-war-two#.XV2WTflfhPY=)). In exchange Germany acquired many products from Switzerland, including arms, and benefited from Swiss banking and railroad connections to Italy (which would have been destroyed in case of an invasion).

Answer (score 2):

There was a documentary last year if I remember well on French/German tv Arte which covered the subject, and its point of view was that despite what Swiss people like to think, they were not the hedgehog in German feet, but more likely the bankers of the third reich, so it had nothing to do with military.

It was explained that in this time, no country in the world wanted to be paid in mark for trade, and Germany desperately needed some raw materials for its war effort. There were two examples I can remember of materials they needed: rubber for tank caterpillar, and tungsten for tank armouring, coming essentially from a mine in Portugal for the last one.

And in all these situations, or when trade couldn't happen directly between Germany and Portugal for example, it was Switzerland who played the role of intermediate: Germans payed Swiss with the gold they stole from occupied countries (including jews), and Swiss payed Portugueses either in Franc or with gold.
So they could not afford to loose their only way to trade abroad and left them alone.

In this French [article](https://www.liberation.fr/cahier-special/1997/12/02/or-nazi-les-lingots-oublies-du-portugal-de-1939-a-1944-lisbonne-aurait-achete-ou-echange-164-tonnes-_223814) covering the Portuguese issue, it is mentioned an amount of 40 tons of gold coming directly from Germany and another 120 tons having transited from Switzerland.

In this other French [article](https://www.cairn.info/revue-materiaux-pour-l-histoire-de-notre-temps-2009-1-page-77.htm), it is written than 80 percent of German gold used abroad by the Reichsbank during world war II transited through Switzerland.

The documentary demonstrated that despite the Allies unofficial warning made to Switzerland in 1944, trade still occurred however, at a lower rate. If I remember well, they talked about a last deal which was paid by gold molten from teeth taken in the camps...

A deal was signed in Washington in [May 1946](https://www.dodis.ch/fr/dossiers-thematiques/e-dossier-70e-anniversaire-de-laccord-de-washington), unfreezing Swiss assets blocked by USA and withdrawing from blacklist name of Swiss companies who traded with Axis during the war, in exchange of 250M CHF.

The last part of the doc was explaining how hard it was in Switzerland nowadays to face this part of their History, especially because they built and where grown with a more glorious legend of the small hedgehog resisting victoriously to the German ogre.

I'll try to find the name of the doc tonight, it was a good watch.

Edit: I think it was this [one](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x4y1m9p), in French

Answer (score 1):

The [Reich](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazi_Germany) annexed or invaded various other Germanic territories, such as [Austria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anschluss) (before the war even began), as well as [Denmark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_invasion_of_Denmark_(1940)), [Norway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Weserubung), [Belgium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Belgium), [Netherland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Netherlands), and [Luxembourg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_invasion_of_Luxembourg) (after it started). More to the point, the Low Countries, as Switzerland, also adopted, initially, a position of neutrality, so your question is certainly reasonable. I believe **one** of the reason**s** behind this inaction to be Switzerland's geographical, historical, cultural, national, and strategic ties to one of [Germany's most trusted allies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis_powers) during the [Second World War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II), namely [Fascist Italy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fascist_Italy_(1922-1943)). (Indeed, [Hitler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler)'s own [Beer Hall Putsch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer_Hall_Putsch) was modeled on [Mussolini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benito_Mussolini)'s [March on Rome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/March_on_Rome)). Of course, Austria also bordered on Italy, but, [unlike Switzerland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_of_Switzerland), it was not home, historically, to any significant [Italian population](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Italian). All other lands, however, were either mostly Germanic, or housed [French](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_France) and [Slavic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_occupation_of_Czechoslovakia) populations, whose (main) fatherland Hitler planned on attacking anyway. It is indeed rather striking that [Germany's incursion into Italian territory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Areas_annexed_by_Nazi_Germany#Partially_incorporated_territories) (in the [Alps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_Zone_of_the_Alpine_Foothills) and [Adriatic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_Zone_of_the_Adriatic_Littoral)) begins only **after** Italy's signing of the [September 1943 Armistice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armistice_of_Cassibile) with the [Allied Forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allies_of_World_War_II). (Just my two cents).

Comment: **GREAT CARE** - I suspect this book is extremely biased [tm] based on a brief skim - but may have some value  [Trading with the Enemy](https://libcom.org/library/allied-multinationals-supply-nazi-germany-world-war-2)

Answer (score 1):

Not impossible, but costly and difficult, to the point of being a net-negative.

I've been to Switzerland and more in other parts of the Alps (Austria and Germany). I'm also interested in history and military strategy. Based on what I've read over the years:

Invading Switzerland is a hard problem due to geography. There is a limited number of roads open all year, and of course the Swiss known them very well. There are hidden bunkers and guns everywhere, just look at [these hidden bunkers](https://www.timeout.com/switzerland/things-to-do/swiss-bunkers-tours-and-museums) for examples. When literally **everything** can be an anti-tank gun waiting for you to come into range, you can either accept terrible casualties or make your invasion a crawl.

Holding any conquered territory suffers from similar problems. Most villages and towns are at the bottom of valleys (where rivers and arable land are, you know?) and a few snipers in the mountains can make your life hell while your chance to get them is effectively zero.

Unlike Greece or Yugoslavia, most of the country is that kind of territory.

As for starvation - mountains are more complicated than that. There are so many [Alms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_transhumance) (mountain pastures) in the Alps that you can easily feed a widely distributed guerilla force from those alone. When you look at a mountain from below, it might seem that it goes up, gets rocky, and then there's the top. But in reality, there are vast areas of land up there, hidden from down by the mountain face. I've been climbing and skiing in the Alps and there are so many places I've been to that were completely invisible from below. You can put entire villages up there and from the valley you would never guess they even exist.

So you would have to run continuous patrols in a difficult terrain that your enemy knows like the back of his hand. If you want to know how that typically turns out, remember the Vietnam war.

And all of that for a small country with almost no strategic value and few ressources.

Comment: Glad you enjoyed your visits to our mountains - but the major swiss population and industrial centers are not located there, neither then nor now. Germany would not have needed to cross any mountains to take the vast majority of the Swiss population and industrial capacity.

Comment: Zürich, Bern, Genf? None of them are far enough from the next mountain range that I'd feel safe as a military commander. Not in the age of artillery.

Comment: Your notion that artillery could have suppressed the german advance (that's what you are suggesting, right?) doesn't seem consistent with swiss military policy at the time. Can you give any sources that document the existence of such artillery stations and how the swiss were intending to use them?

Comment: Not to halt the advance, but to support guerilla actions and force the constant presence of a large occupation force. The whole point of the Swiss military strategy, as I understand it, is to give up the land, but make it too costly for any invader to keep it.

Comment: @meriton: But major population centers are not Switzerland, which is what the question asks about.  Claiming that taking them means the country is conquered would be like an invader taking the Boston/Washington and San Francisco/San Diego metro area, and then claiming that they'd conquered the US.

Comment: ... which is why I mention that all heavy industry is located in the Swiss plateau. That is, the Germans could have severed Swiss supply lines for weapons and amno without ever venturing into mountainous terrain. Yes, you can wage guerilla warfare from the mountains - but for how long?

Comment: @jamesqf: The [Swiss Plateau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Plateau#Population) contains the majority of the Swiss population, and the entire heavy industry. If you want to compare to US geography, it would be more like this: Image that a foreign power invades the US, and the US defense strategy says to fall back, and only defend the Rocky Mountains and Alaska. Calling a country "impossible to invade" when its most valuable territory,  the majority of its population, and the entire industrial capacity can be taken freely seems highly misleading to me.

Comment: That's not really a good comparison. Not many places on the Swiss Plateau are more than 100 km away from the nearest mountain. Meanwhile, not many interesting places in the US are **less** than ten times that from the Rocky Mountains.

Comment: @meriton: I know about Switzerland: I've lived there (mostly in the French-speaking part).  The point is that while an enemy may hold a few cities &c, as long as the hinterland is unoccupied, he will face constant attack.

Comment: Also, if you drive through Switzerland, which I do pretty often, the trained eye will note the bunkers on either side of the motorway, and the doors in roofs of tunnels where demolition charges can be installed, the steel spiked flaps in the road which can rise up and kill your tyres... I expect these days of long range artillery these installations are no longer relevant, but the first time I observed these things I was impressed.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question:**  I'm simply asking if the defense of Switzerland during WW2 was overrated. Many people claim that the country was impossible to occupy, I just want to know if this is not clearly exaggerated.

It is a myth that Switzerland was impossible to invade or occupy.  Hitler in 1940 described Switzerland as a "pimple on the face of Europe", as he developed his plans to invade.  **[Operation Tannenbaum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Tannenbaum)**.

Why he never invaded is reflected in timing and reward more than an aversion to doing battle with the Swiss army or on Swiss terrain.

Yes, Switzerland improved its defenses at the ontset of WW2.  Yes, the mountains and terrain of Switzerland would make the invasion harder.  But does anyone believe Switzerland's Alps and army were a greater deterrent than Russia's vast distances and cold winter, both of which defeated Napoleon?  Or France's well equipped and significantly larger army?  Or Britain with her Navy, RAF and Channel?  Or the United States with an entire Ocean and vast population?   Germany was at war with all these more existential threats rather than the Swiss.

Hitler's aversion to invading Switzerland came down to timing and reward.  He was waiting for the time, and he really already had most of the reward a conquest of the Swiss would grant him.

**Timing**
Hitler was busy with the allies.  If and when Hitler was free of them,  popular wisdom is he would have invaded Switzerland.   He already had his plans drawn up.  The only thing which saved the Swizz was he likely hadn't gotten around to them yet.

**Reward**
Basically there was precious little reward for Germany in invading Switzerland in WWII.   Germany was Switzerland's main trading partner before and during the war.  On Switzerland's side, Switzerland is and was an industrial country with very few raw materials to fuel its industry.  During WWII much of that fuel in the form of coal and raw materials came from Germany which surrounded Switzerland.

> **[The Economics of Neutrality: Spain, Sweden and Switzerland in the Second World War (2011)](http://etheses.lse.ac.uk/178/1/Golson_The_Economics_of_Neutrality.pdf)** - page 294
> Between 1939 and 1945 Germany exported 10,267,000 tons of coal to Switzerland. In 1943 these imports supplied 41% of Swiss energy requirements. In the same period Switzerland sold electric power to Germany equivalent to 6,077,000 tons of coal.

.
Germany enjoyed the benefits of Switzerland's industrial output for important war materials such as ball-bearings.   Germany also enjoyed the ability to transport goods through Switzerland on her railways to Germany's primary ally in Italy.  Germany also enjoyed a brisk business with Switzerland's banks where they squirrelled away their loot and booty from across Europe.   So overall there was very little to entice Germany to invade, they already realized the benefits of good trade, travel and cooperative relationship with Switzerland.   Truth be told, these things didn't stop Hitler from invading Austria.   Which brings us back to timing.

> **NY Times: [The (Not So) Neutrals of World War 2](https://www.nytimes.com/1997/01/26/weekinreview/the-not-so-neutrals-of-world-war-ii.html)**
> ''The romantic idea of the Swiss citizen army standing between it and disaster in the war was always nonsense,'' said Arno J. Mayer, a professor of history at Princeton University. ''Given the fact it borders Germany, it was natural for it to lean more toward the Axis powers. It is the new spirit of our times that has led to the current scrutiny.''

Comment: I don't think Schweiz was Germany's main trading partner - The UK is more correct (a far larger municipal market.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not impossible, as any country can invade another, but if you mean conquer it'd be quite hard, as the Alps would hinder German movement, and there wasn't any real motivation to invade Switzerland, as Switzerland is a mainly German country that focused on neutrality and didn't have any good resources the German war machine needed like oil. The only way I can see an invasion happening is if Germany decided to go thru the Maginot line with Switzerland instead of Belgium, which would strategically be a bad idea as Belgium's terrain is much more flat than the Alps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer to a silghtly different, but highly relevant question:

Why didn't Germany attack Switzerland?

There's a multitude of reasons, in no particular order (all links in German):

- Luck ([source 1](https://blog.tagesanzeiger.ch/nevermindthemarkets/index.php/13094/warum-wurde-die-schweiz-im-zweiten-weltkrieg-verschont/#comments))
- Military deterrent ([source 1](https://blog.tagesanzeiger.ch/nevermindthemarkets/index.php/13094/warum-wurde-die-schweiz-im-zweiten-weltkrieg-verschont/#comments))
- Lack of a good logistic opportunity for the Axis ([source 1](https://blog.tagesanzeiger.ch/nevermindthemarkets/index.php/13094/warum-wurde-die-schweiz-im-zweiten-weltkrieg-verschont/#comments))
- Willing partner in trade ([source 1](https://blog.tagesanzeiger.ch/nevermindthemarkets/index.php/13094/warum-wurde-die-schweiz-im-zweiten-weltkrieg-verschont/#comments))
- North south transportation, through the Gotthard tunnel, and the expected collapse of said tunnel in case of invasion ([source 2](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transit_durch_den_Gotthard_1940%E2%80%931945))
- Germany's long term strategy of generating support among "Aryan" countries and "Aryan" occupied territories ([source 3](https://www.nzz.ch/schweiz/weshalb-blieb-die-schweiz-im-zweiten-weltkrieg-verschont-ld.1411372))
- Expectation of eventual peaceful annexation ([source 3](https://www.nzz.ch/schweiz/weshalb-blieb-die-schweiz-im-zweiten-weltkrieg-verschont-ld.1411372))

Any one of these reasons, with the exception of the first one, is not a sufficient explanation on its own. Taking the [Swiss Plateau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Plateau), installing a German friendly government (or rather, keeping the half that was German friendly already), and hoping that the army in the mountains eventually surrenders would have been a simple and viable strategy that the Germans were well aware of.

Answer (score -1):

No, Switzerland was not self sufficient food wise. While the mountainous terrain is an advantage militarily, it is a big problem when you can't trade with your neighbors.

occupying the country would be relatively easy for the same reasons, hunger humbles even the most determined.

I would bet a three month blockade, and air campaign (on critical infrastructure) and the swiss would surrender.

Comment: While Switzerland was indeed not self sufficient when WWII began, they radically transformed their agricultural sector as part of the [Anbauschlacht](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_Wahlen). By the end of the war, the agricultural area in Switzerland had doubled, bringing the country close to self sufficiency. And of course the Swiss held a strategic food reserve, so a 3 month blockade would have been far too short to cause hunger.

Comment: @meriton,  during WWII as much as half of Switzerland's energy in the form of coal came from Germany.   As the allies bombed the German Industrial base especially ball-bearings at huge cost of air crews and planes;  Switzerland's industrial base was augmenting Germany's manufacturing capacity.    Swisserland was neutral in WWII in name only.   I'll give you probable out of necessity.

Comment: @JMS As soon as the war began, Switzerland started massively electrifying its train network that was still not already electrified to stop importinc coal. Electricity is produced with dams in the alps and made Switzerland energy-autartic. By 1941 this was mostly done. Since then, Switzerland is one of the only country in the world (with Austria maybe) where 99% of the rail network is electrified.

Comment: @Bregalad  Between 1939 and 1945 Germany exported 10,267,000 tons of coal to Switzerland. In 1943 these imports supplied 41% of Swiss energy requirements. In the same period Switzerland sold electric power to Germany equivalent to 6,077,000 tons of coal.  [The Economics of Neutrality: Spain, Sweden and Switzerland in the Second World War -2011](http://etheses.lse.ac.uk/178/1/Golson_The_Economics_of_Neutrality.pdf)  Page 294

Comment: @Bregalad that is why i included an air campaign to knock out any critical infrastructure.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to History.stackexchange

Your question is interesting, and a lot of points were highlighted by other contributors. I would like to add some points:

We are in a World War, not only in the fight of Axis/Germany versus Switzerland. One of the contributor spoke in the conditions of an uchrony where the Axis is victorious. What could be interesting is to consider the different periods when Axis could have invaded Switzerland.

Hindisght: I am not considering here the causes: why would Axis invade Switzerland, but only how it could do it without leaving to the Allies all the other fronts.

1939: Germany is the only fighter of the Axis: it could not invade Switzerland at the same time as Poland, without creating a frank reaction from the French and English armies. So if any reason leads Germany to threaten Switzerland, Germany would wait 1940.

1940: The best year considering the strategy: While attacking Belgium, Germany could also creates a new front on the right flank of the Allies. It would be somehow a way to secure the southern flank of the Sedan Breakthrough.
Italy could help, and after the Anchluss, the Axis have three directions from which to attack Switzerland: North, East and South. However, as others said, the mountains are a great obstacle: the French defended with a great efficiency the Alpes, so the Swiss Army could have done the same.
At the end, it is probable that the bulk of the Wehrmacht would have concentrated against France, winning the war and reaching Geneva from the West before the center of Swiss is reached from the East/North/South.
This would be the perfect conditions for the Swiss Army to become an important Resistance movement.

1941: The perfect year on a tactical point of view: attack from all sides, with the same fights as against Yougoslavia or in Greece, with panzerdivisions having a good dotation in infantry and artilery, and a massive support from the Luftwaffe. Siwtzerland stood no chance but could resist for a long time.

1942, 1943: those years are the same: not that much troops available, with all the fronts, but for example, the troops used against the Yougoslavian Resistance movements could be directed against Switzerland. The RAF would be too far to support Swiss aviation, however a lot of bombers and fighters would be distracted from the major fights on the East Front and in Africa.

1944: The advance in Italy would lead Switzerland to be an opportunity for the Allies: so maybe the Axis will not take the risk to have a front in the back of Kesselring's troops in Italy.

1945: No way! The Allies are at the gates, not any troops are available to defend Switzerland.

Answer (score -2):

Totally new to this site, and not an historian. But... no other answer is considering weapons. AFAIK Switzerland doesn't/didn't make its own weapons. Once the war is started, anything spent or destroyed by the enemy won't be replaced. Switzerland is neutral, so it has no allies to provide them with weapons/ammunition, and even if they are/were rich enough to purchase abroad, there are procurement delays, and the enemy can intercept the delivery. So if the guerilla could last, the military would lose a war of attrition (however expensive it would be for the enemy, given the tactical difficulties).

Comment: That's ridiculous; Switzerland was actually [exporting weapons and ammunition during WWII](https://www.uek.ch/de/schlussbericht/Publikationen/Zusammenfassungenpdf/11d.pdf) (not much, granted, but it does show they had a surplus).

Comment: The Axis would be able to block any imports to Switzerland, which would make arms production very difficult. Also, the Swiss arms factories were in the Mittelland (like in Oerlikon) and would be vulnerable to both invasion and bombing.

Comment: -1: Not only Switzerland manufactured it's weapons (and exported them) back then, but it still does now. This answer is counter-factual.

Comment: @Bregalad They do planes (beyond trainers), tanks, heavy guns, bombs? Where do they get the steel? or iron ore and coal?

Comment: @meriton From the very doc you cite: * The product range was extremely narrow: automatic 20 mm cannon and its components against earth targets, for air defense and the arming of aircraft and warships, 20 mm ammunition, clock igniters and parts thereof of the German type S / 30 for 8.8 cm Ammunition and larger, Dixi GPA detonators, in military optics in advance coincidence telemeter 80 cm and 150 cm.* 20mm cannon? Do you realize how small that is? It would barely scratch a tank.

Comment: @xenoid I am by far no expert in weapons, and actually I have no clue. But the statement "switzerland didn't make weapons" and the statement "weapon made in Switzerland were too small to scratch a tank" are very different statements. You made the former in your answer, which is factually wrong. Steel was imported but there were different countries they could import it from. Also, like Germany itself, they could recycle it from previous usages if there was a need.